# rails form submit not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit

Trying to create a table that will display the results a users search that will allow the user to add the required result to a database table.

When I first created and tested the submit button was disabled, so I added `disable_with: false`  to the submit action. But its still not firing.

What have I overlooked?

```
<tbody>
    <% @stock_items.each do |stock| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= stock.product_code %></td>
        <td><%= stock.desc1.titleize %></td>
        <td class="text-right"><%= stock.uoi %></td>
        <td class="text-right"><%= strip_trailing_zero(stock.qty_free) %></td>
        <td class="text-right"><%= number_to_gbp(stock.price)%></td>
        <td class="text-right"><%= number_to_percentage(((stock.price-stock.cost_sop)/stock.price)*100,precision: 0)%></td>
        <%= form_tag new_customer_opportunity_sop_header_sop_detail_path(@customer,@opportunity, @sop_header) do %>
        <td><%= hidden_field_tag 'stock_id', stock.id %>
          <%= submit_tag 'Add', data: { disable_with: false } %></td>
        <% end %>
       </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: what does "not firing" mean? do you see any error on the browser's console? something on the network tab? on the rails server logs?

Comment: @arieljuod Nothing occurs on the browsers console, or the network tab or the rails server logs. It just does nothing.

Comment: hmmm, try moving the `form` tag INSIDE the `td` tag, it's weird that it's arround it, maybe the browser can't render it right that way. I don't see anything wrong on the code, i'd recommend you to try to simplify the form and add things until you see the problem (start with just a form for the first stock item and check it works, then add the table for the first item, then add the look, just to narrow it down)

Comment: Thanks @arieljuod thats what it was. I moved it into the `td` and it worked, thanks for your help